# @JsonIgnore | @JsonManagedReference @JsonBackRefernece is not working with @onetoone mapping if the reference is set as composite key

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have the following tables:
Parent:

```
desc parent;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Child:

```
 desc child;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| name      | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| test      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| parent_id | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Here, in the child class, I have the primary key as composite key = (name, parent_id).

Entity for parent:

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "parent")
@Data
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @Column
    private String id;

    @OneToOne (mappedBy = "compKey.parent") //If I change this relationship to one-many, json ignore works fine
    private Child child;
}
```

Entity for Child class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Child {
    @Embeddable
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class CompKey implements Serializable {

        @OneToOne //If I change One-One to Many-One and similarly One-Many on Parent class referencing the child class, json ignore works fine
        @JoinColumn
        @JsonIgnore //Json ignore is not working and is giving stackoverflow exception for one to one
        private Parent parent;

        @Column
        private String name;
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    private CompKey compKey;

    @Column
    private String test;
}
```

Now whenever I am performing

```
parentRepo.findById(id); // Thowing stackoverflow exception
```

I am getting **stackoverflow exception**.

This does not occur. If the relationship is set to @OneToMany on parent side and @ManyToOne on child side.

**This also does not occur if I do not use the composite key and set the reference to the Parent without using the @Embedded id**

Example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Child {
    
    @Id
    @Column
    private String id;

    @Column
    private String test;

    @OneToOne 
    @JoinColumn
    @JsonIgnore //Json ignore is working and is not giving stack overflow exception, here I am not using embedded id
    private Parent parent;
}
```

findById works perfectly fine in the above case and no error.

I wanted to use composite key with the reference of parent table included in the child table.
Is there any reason why I can not set the back reference while using Composite key?

Comment: Please explain **when and where** you get the error? Also don't use `@Data` with JPA entities, as it will generate wrong methods see https://deinum.biz/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/, especially `toString` is problematic if you decide to logging fro instance.

Comment: I am getting error while performing findById Operation on parent class

Comment: I doubt it is on the single `findById` but rather some logging or the fact that you are exposing JSON. Please include the stacktrace.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table so we can see what MySQL is working with.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the problem you are trying to solve  Can you use @MapsId in the child entity? Is there a requirement for a bidirectional relation here? We can eliminate the bidirectional relationship by sharing the primary key from the parent entity. Let's clean up the child entity class.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Child {
    @Id
    private String id;

    private String test;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    @JsonIgnore
    @MapsId
    private Parent parent;
}
```